# Extracting JSON from cURL results

Tags: php, regex, json, curl, preg-replace

I'm new to regex and I'm trying to grab the JSON response from a cURL request in PHP.

I was thinking of using preg_match_all.

*Edit*: Should have mentioned the full response from curl_exec() includes header information which is why I need to extract the JSON.

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1 WWW-Authenticate:  Digest realm="",  qop="auth", [... etc]
```

The JSON I want looks something like this (following all headers):

```
{  "requests" :  
  [ { 
     "request_id" : 10298, 
     "name" : "CURL Test2",  
     "submitter" : "First Last",  
     "hide" : false,  
     "priority" : 10,  
     "tags" : [ "label 2" ],  
     "body" : 
          { "type" : "html", "content" : "" },  
     "runs" : 0  
   } ] 
  }
```

Was hoping to just grab everything between the curly braces. However, when I do this it grabs everything from the **first opening brace** to the ***first*** closing brace. For extensibility, I just want to grab everything within and including the first opening brace and the ***last*** closing brace.

Technically it could just start at the first opening brace and return everything until end of the response (there's nothing following the JSON).

Thoughts?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Regex is great, but definitely not the correct tool for this.

There is a function [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) that can handle this for you.

It will return the structure as an object. You can return it as an array by setting the second argument to `TRUE`. Even if PHP didn't have this function, you are better off writing or using an existing JSON parser than trying to extract portions with regex.

If you are using the headers and need to separate the body into a separate variable, you should do something like the following where `$ch` is an instance of curl and `$result` is the return of `curl_exec()`.

```
$headerLen = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE); 
$curlBody = substr($result, $headerLen);`
```

Comment: The full response from the curl_exec() includes HTTP headers etc. Can json_decode() handle this?

Comment: @djreed No, but you can disable the output of headers and only return the response body can't you? Alternatively you could do `$json = trim(strstr($response, "\n"))`.

Comment: Not sure how to return just the response body from curl_exec(). Trimming the string does not work.

Comment: @djreed There should be a `\n` between the headers and body, so the code in the comment should work. Or just set `CURLOPT_HEADER` option to false.

Comment: Just realised, that should be splitting on `"\n\n"`, not just one, which would occur after the first header :)

Answer (score 2):

as this helped me near to the result but only "near"  want to share my result ..

```
$json = array ( "firstname" => "john" , "lastname" => "Doe") ; 
$jsonheader = array ( "Accept: application/json" 
, "Content-type:application/json" 
, "Authorization: OAuth oauth_token=xxxxx" ) ;

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://myurl.com?oAuth=12341231234' ); // set the target url
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1 ); // howmany parameter to post
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json ); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true ); // don't give anything back 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE );  // need this to evaluate the response .. 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $jsonheader ); // it is httpheader not httpheader"s" 

$result = curl_exec ($ch);

curl_close ($ch);
$resultarr = explode ( "\n" , $result ) ;
$httpval = explode ( " " , $resultarr[0] ) ; // explode the first line

for ( $i=1 ;  $i < count( $resultarr) ; $i++ ) {
    if ( is_array (json_decode( $resultarr[$i] , true)) ){
        $resultvals  = json_decode( $resultarr[$i] , true) ;
    }       
}
if ( $resultvals['YourKey'] <> '' ) {  // any accepted value in the response ... 
    if ( $httpval[1] == "201" )  {
        $error = 0 ; //  no error Overwrite error 2 
    } else {
        $error = 1 ;  // http response was not 201  .. 
    }
} else {
   $error = 2 ;  // any other error like "no response" or "other error"   
 }
```

Comment: Explain what you mean by "only near" - that way the people reading can understand what might be missing/needed.